# Different types of aggregation in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, aggregate

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
sub = c("X001","X001", "X001","X002","X002","X001","X002","X001","X002","X002","X002","X002") 
revenue = c(20, 15, -10,-25,20,-20, 17,9,14,12, -9, 11)

df = data.frame(sub, revenue)
```

I want to aggregate it in such a way that the second column should show the sum of all revenue for the sub, the third column should show the sum on absolute value, the fourth column should show the sum of all positive values and the fifth column should show the sum of all negative values.

The result should look like this:

```
Sub     All Sum       Absolute Sum       Positive Sum       Negative Sum

X001     14            74                 44                 -30
X002     40            108                74                 -34
```

I've written code that calculates the All sum:

```
y<-aggregate(df$revenue, by=list(Feature=x$Sub), FUN=sum)
```

I would really appreciate it if someone more knowledgable in R would help me in calculating the other three columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do that with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
group_by(sub)%>%
summarise(All_Sum=sum(revenue),Absolute_Sum=sum(abs(revenue)),
          Positive_Sum=(sum(revenue[revenue>0])),Negative_Sum=(sum(revenue[revenue<0])))

     sub All_Sum Absolute_Sum Positive_Sum Negative_Sum
  <fctr>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1   X001      14           74           44          -30
2   X002      40          108           74          -34
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~sub, df, function(a) c(sum(a), sum(abs(a)), sum(a[a>0]), sum(a[a<0])))

#  sub revenue.1 revenue.2 revenue.3 revenue.4
#1 X001        14        74        44       -30
#2 X002        40       108        74       -34
```

Comment: Thats really cool, I didn't know the aggregate function could be extended like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(All_Sum = sum(revenue), Absolute_Sum =  sum(abs(revenue)),
   Positive_Sum = sum(revenue[revenue>0]), Negative_Sum = sum(revenue[revenue<0])), by = sub]  
#    sub All_Sum Absolute_Sum Positive_Sum Negative_Sum
#1: X001      14           74           44          -30
#2: X002      40          108           74          -34
```